# NSDictionary Search

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

My NSDictionary is only retrieving the first array in the Dictionary.
 I have no idea why its behaving this way.

Here is the search

```
//Loop through the DataDictionary for ORIGIN and DESTINATION
    for (NSMutableDictionary *floors in [MapData allfloors]){
        //Check if found then set roomListTxt and defaultImage from the Dictionary values
        if ([floors[ORIGIN] isEqualToString:origin] && [floors[DESTINATION] isEqualToString:destination]) {
            searchResults.roomListTxt = floors[DESTINATION_ROOMS];
            searchResults.defaultImage = floors[MAP_IMAGE];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:searchResults animated:YES];
            //break;
        } else {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops!!" message:@"Working to add more routes." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            break;
        }
    }
```

Here is a definition of the Dictionary

```
NSDictionary *d1Dictionary = @{ORIGIN : @"A1",
                               DESTINATION : @"D1",
                               ORIGIN_ROOMS : @"A101, A102, A113",
                               DESTINATION_ROOMS : @"D100, D100C, D101, D102, D103, D105, D107, D111, D113",
                               MAP_IMAGE : [UIImage imageNamed:@"A1-D1.png"]};
[floorsInformation addObject:d1Dictionary];

NSDictionary *d2Dictionary = @{ORIGIN : @"A1",
                               DESTINATION : @"M1",
                               ORIGIN_ROOMS : @"A101, A102, A113",
                               DESTINATION_ROOMS : @"M104, M105, M106, M107",
                               MAP_IMAGE : [UIImage imageNamed:@"A1-M1.png"]};
[floorsInformation addObject:d2Dictionary];
```

The input parameters from '*origin*' and '*destination*' are equal to the "*floors[ORIGIN]*" and "*floors[DESTINATION]*" respectively.

Comment: There are no "arrays" in either of the dictionaries you show above.

Comment: And you really need to learn basic programming principles before you tackle Objective-C.

Comment: The dictionaries above are stored in an array...???

Comment: You tell us the dictionaries are in an array and only one element of the array is being retrieved, but you don't show us where the array is declared or initialized.  So far as we can tell there is no array.

Comment: Haha, I get you point but trust me, the array is there...

Comment: Nevertheless, your  question should be closed for lack of necessary information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `else` block is inside the loop. It is only showing the first result because on the second loop, your condition evaluates to `NO`, triggering the alert and `break` command.

You can verify this by setting a breakpoint and stepping through the code. You can resolve the issue by checking for the appropriate data before or after the iteration loop, as appropriate for your app's feature.

For example:

```
for (NSMutableDictionary *floors in [MapData allfloors]){
    //Check if found then set roomListTxt and defaultImage from the Dictionary values
    if ([floors[ORIGIN] isEqualToString:origin] && [floors[DESTINATION] isEqualToString:destination]) {
        searchResults.roomListTxt = floors[DESTINATION_ROOMS];
        searchResults.defaultImage = floors[MAP_IMAGE];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:searchResults animated:YES];
        return;
    }
}


// due to the 'return' statement, this code won't get called if a match is made
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops!!" message:@"Working to add more routes." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
```

Comment: I added a breakpoint and it was retrieving the array objects... It was at that point that i decided to post it in here... I see what you mean. I knew the for loop was causing the malfunction, I just didn't know how it was causing it. Also, the data I need is been searched for in the loop, how do I 'check' the returned array when it's outside the loop? Thank for your help.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do so I don't know what to tell you about how to check it. Can you describe what this function should do?

Comment: I have dictionaries stored in an array and if user enters values in a textbook, it should search the array of dictionaries and instantiate some variables from the values in the dictionary. That about sums it up.

Comment: Thanks @AaronBrager. Now I see their is a difference between break and return.